# Обход всех radio box на форме js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма на странице. На ней расположены 3 группы с разным количеством input'ов типа radio
Как можно получить значение name всех отмеченных инпутов при переключении любого radiobox'а?

```
 <form class="conf">
   <div class="conf_group">
      <b class="conf_title">Группа 1</b>
      <div class="form__input  form__input--radio">
         <input class="jchange_param" id="g1_1" type="radio" name="G_1" value="1" checked="">
         <label for="g1_1">Значение 1</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="conf_group">
      <b class="conf_title">Группа 2</b>
      <div class="form__input  form__input--radio">
         <input class="jchange_param" id="g2_2" type="radio" name="G_2" value="0" checked="">
         <label for="g2_2">Значение 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__input  form__input--radio">
         <input class="jchange_param" id="g2_1" type="radio" name="G_2" value="1">
         <label for="g2_1">Значение 2</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="conf_group">
      <b class="conf_title">Группа 3</b>
      <div class="form__input  form__input--radio">
         <input class="jchange_param" id="g3_1" type="radio" name="G_3" value="0" checked="">
         <label for="g3_1">Значение 1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form__input  form__input--radio">
         <input class="jchange_param" id="g3_2" type="radio" name="G_3" value="1">
         <label for="g3_2">Значение 2</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let values = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]:checked')).map(item=>item.name);
```

Comment: Можно `[...document.querySelectorAll()]` вместо Array from

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант вполне рабочий. Но он получает данные от всех инпутов на страницу. Как ограничиться только текущей формы?

Comment: Если под текущей формой подразумевается определенная группа, то можно добавить в выборку поиск по атрибуту name - `document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]:checked [name=G_n]')`, где n - номер этой вашей группы. А если надо перед получением массива значений определять, к какой группе относится новоизмененный инпут и выбирать только значения этой группы, то нужно функции, которую вы используете для отлавливания изменений инпутов передать объект `event` и получать значение `name` данного инпута через `let name = event.target.name`. Потом - `querySelectorAll('[type=radio]:checked [name=${name}]')`